Лог ошибочных запросов и транзакций в MySQL, существует ли вообще? или как его получить
Суть в том, что у меня в коде формируется огромная транзакция из десятков таблиц. Естественно в какой-то из них происходит ошибка и транзакция завершается с ошибкой.
При этом логи MySQL в принципе фиксируют только изменения, которые были произведены по факту, и никаких ошибок. Во всяком случае об этом четко написано в мануале

А мне нужно знать в какой именно части транзакции происходит сбой, чтобы быстро определить место (в коде), где я неправильно что-то сделал.
Увы все мануалы только про обычные логи, которые мне особо и ничего не дают((
То есть используется чисто для бэкапов. А сам результат операции можно посмотреть только если делаешь запрос через консоль. А вот в коде я могу получить только "true = выполнено" или "false = не выполнено".
Я просто не верю что нет способа. Почему нигде ни одного мануала на эту тему(

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.
